# what is a null pointer in c

Tags: c, pointers, null

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct findEntry
    {
        int value;
        struct entry *next;
    };

    struct entry n1, n2, n3;
    struct entry *list_pointer = &n1;

    n1.value = 100;
    n1.next = &n2;

    n2.value = 200;
    n2.next = &n2;

    n3.value = 300;
    n3.next = (stuct entry *) 0;

    while (list_pointer != (struct entry *)0) {
        printf("%i\n", list_pointer->value);
        list_pointer = list_pointer->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand what the syntax `(struct entry *) 0`, means here. In the book I am reading it says it is a null pointer. I tried looking online but I didn't know exactly what to type. The Google search results I got for 'NULL pointer' were different from what I expected.

Comment: There is also a typo in `n2.next = &n2;`, meaning that we will never reach `n3`. I would just throw this bad example away and study some other code.

Comment: `(struct entry *)0` is just a bad way to write `NULL`. Get a new book.

Comment: Note that your code defines a type `struct findEntry`, which contains a pointer to an incomplete type `struct entry`.  You can't define `n1` etc becuase `struct entry` is an incomplete type.  It takes fewest changes to define `struct entry` instead of `struct findEntry` — or you can change `struct entry` to `struct findEntry` throughout.  Also, there's a typo in `n3.next = (stuct entry *) 0;` — `struct` has an `r` in it.  Please — post code that compiles!

Comment: Also, your line `n2.next = &n2;` gives you a cycle in your list, and leaves `n3` unused.  Your printing loop is going to run for a long time once the code compiles.

Comment: I think that the author of the code was using the C++ compiler.

Answer (score 7):

Any pointer type with the value 0 is called a null pointer. Here is the explanation from the C standard §6.3.2.3:

> 3. An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression
>      cast to type void *, is called a null pointer constant. If a null
>      pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the resulting
>      pointer, called a null pointer, is guaranteed to compare unequal to a
>      pointer to any object or function

Answer (score 5):

Null pointer is a pointer that points to memory address 0.  Most system reserve this address so that no object will ever reside in there.  This reservation allows to use it as blank address.

If you try to read or write from null pointer you will get runtime error which is sometimes called segmentation fault, or null pointer exception.

In your example the null pointer is used to indicate end of the list.  So this condition `(struct entry *) 0,` checks if you have reached end of the list and iteration should stop

Usually it considered better form to use constant NULL instead of literal value 0.  This makes code more readable, and also covers very rare case when NULL pointer is not a 0

The cast `(struct entry *)` is just to avoid compiler warning, because literal 0 is of type integer not a pointer.  That's another reason to use constant NULL, because it is usually defined as `(void*) 0` which compares nicely to any pointer value without a warning from compiler

Comment: Note that `0` is a perfectly satisfactory null pointer constant.  Some compilers may warn about it, but the standard most definitely does not require any such warning.  Using plain `0` with no cast is legitimate according to the standard.

Answer (score 1):

It does exactly the same job as NULL which is (void *)0 as defined in the C standard..

Comment: It's not exactly the same as `(void *)0` because the type is different (one is a void pointer, the other is a `struct entry *`).

Comment: I bet the original author was using the C++ compiler and was getting errors. That is the probable reason of this strange (in C) assignment.

Comment: [C11 §7.19 Common definitions `<stddef.h>` ¶3](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html) says: _The macros are
`NULL`
which expands to an implementation-defined null pointer constant; …_ and a null pointer constant is defined as quoted by [medalib](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7383242/medalib) in their [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49712550/15168).  It is not necessarily `(void *)0`, though that is a very common value that is widely used.

Answer (score 0):

A null pointer is initialized a pointer as invalid or it is marked as uninitalized. The NULL pointer is also available
instead of the next pointer and thus also indicates the end of a list.