# Can only pointers hold NULL values?

Tags: c, pointers, null

I was trying to set a struct to NULL but the compiler was saying "invalid initializer", but the moment I made a pointer for that struct it worked properly.

```
struct node {
 int value;
 struct node * left;
 struct node * right;
};

struct node a = NULL; /* doesn't work */
struct node * b = NULL; /* works fine */
```

Answer (score 4):

Instances of structs can not be NULL per-se, but they can be zero'd out on initialization.

```
 struct node a = {0}; // equivalent to setting a.value=0, a.left=NULL, and a.right=NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

to the most basic definition `NULL` is defined as `0` ( usually a macro  in the form `#define NULL 0`) and is defined in `stdlib.h`

so `NULL` (or its value) could be assign to an integer value or any equivalent scalar type.

`struct` are compound data type(like `array`s) and would not be assigned with a scalar type (short of some typecast).

Comment: An implementation may define `NULL` to be zero, but C programmers cannot rely on this. Per C 2018 7.19 3, the `NULL` macro expands to an implementation-defined *null pointer constant*. Per 6.3.2.3 3, a null pointer constant is either an integer constant expression with value 0 or such an expression cast to `void *`. When an implementation chooses the latter, `NULL` has a pointer type; it is not an integer 0.

Answer (score 1):

`NULL` means a pointer that points to nothing or is empty. A struct doesn't point anywhere, so **assigning NULL to it doesn't make sense.** If you want to initialize all fields of the struct to zero then it's irrelevant to NULL

In C [`NULL` is an implementation-defined null pointer constant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/NULL), which may be

> - an integer constant expression with the value ​0​
> - an integer constant expression with the value 0 cast to the type void*

So if `var = NULL` works if var is an arithmetic type and NULL is defined as 0, but probably won't when NULL is defined as `(void*)0`. Anyway semantically it doesn't mean that the integer is a NULL pointer, it's just a variable with value 0

See [what is a null pointer in c](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49712466/995714)