# What is an Integer constant expression in C programming?

Tags: c, constants, literals, null-pointer

While reading answers for a question, I came across this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49712550/15933960  . This answer contains this following statement -

> An **integer constant expression** with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type void *, is called a null pointer constant. If a null pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a null pointer, is guaranteed to compare unequal to a pointer to any object or function.

In this statement, What does the term **Integer constant expression** mean?

Comment: Have you had google this? Please read [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.2.0?topic=expressions-integer-constant)

Answer (score 1):

C 2018 6.6 6 and 7 say:

> An *integer constant expression* shall have integer type and shall only have operands that are integer constants, enumeration constants, character constants, `sizeof` expressions whose results are integer constants, `_Alignof` expressions, and floating constants that are the immediate operands of casts. Cast operators in an integer constant expression shall only convert arithmetic types to integer types, except as part of an operand to the `sizeof` or `_Alignof` operator.

> More latitude is permitted for constant expressions in initializers. Such a constant expression shall be, or evaluate to, one of the following:
>
> — an arithmetic constant expression,
>
> — a null pointer constant,
>
> — an address constant, or
>
> — an address constant for a complete object type plus or minus an integer constant expression.

*Arithmetic constant expression* is defined in 6.6 8:

> An *arithmetic constant expression* shall have arithmetic type and shall only have operands that are integer constants, floating constants, enumeration constants, character constants, `sizeof` expressions whose results are integer constants, and `_Alignof` expressions. Cast operators in an arithmetic constant expression shall only convert arithmetic types to arithmetic types, except as part of an operand to a `sizeof` or `_Alignof` operator.

*Address constant* is defined in 6.6 9:

> An address constant is a null pointer, a pointer to an lvalue designating an object of static storage duration, or a pointer to a function designator; it shall be created explicitly using the unary `&` operator or an integer constant cast to pointer type, or implicitly by the use of an expression of array or function type. The array-subscript `[]` and member-access `.` and `->` operators, theaddress `&` and indirection `*` unary operators, and pointer casts may be used in the creation of an address constant, but the value of an object shall not be accessed by use of these operators.

And 6.6 10 opens the door to other forms:

> An implementation may accept other forms of constant expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Integer constant expression

An integer constant expression is an expression that consists only of

*
operators other than assignment, increment, decrement, function-call, or comma, except that cast operators can only cast arithmetic types to integer types

- integer constants
- enumeration constants
- character constants
- floating constants, but only if they are immediately used as operands of casts to integer type
- sizeof operators whose operands are not VLA (since C99)
- _Alignof operators (since C11)

Integer constant expressions are evaluated at compile time. The following contexts require expressions that are known as integer constant expressions:

- The size of a bit field.
- The value of an enumeration constant
- The case label of a switch statement
- The size of a non-VLA (since C99) array
- Integer to pointer implicit conversion.
- The index in an array designator
  (since C99)
- The first argument of _Static_assert (since C11)
- The integer argument of _Alignas (since C11)